Автоматическое обновление расширения, установленного извне
Я начал создавать расширение для браузера Chrome и Яндекс браузера. В процессе работы у меня возник вопрос: как будет происходить обновление расширения? Я искал информацию в интернете, но нашёл только записи с 2016-20 года и этот способ больше не актуален.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать? Чтобы я мог загрузить расширение на свой сервер и оттуда выгружать его.
Кроме того, возможно ли посмотреть всё это без загрузки расширения в Chrome Store?
